# Filtering posts by tag on Tumblr page?

Tags: php, javascript, tumblr

I am trying to ensure only posts of a certain tag show up on my homepage of my tumblr, (i.e. posts tagged "News"). Can it be done, and how?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible but would involve using Tumblr's API. Below is an example using the JSON API and jQuery...

```
$.getJSON("http://{Name}.tumblr.com/api/read/json?tagged='[WHATEVER TAG YOU SPECIFY]'&callback=?", function(data) {     
    // Rest of code here...         
});
```

The {Name} tag automatically places the tumblr's name into the API URL. From here you would likely use jQuery to append to the resultant post data to somewhere on your page like a "Featured Posts" div.

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/