# How can I put posts with certain tags in certain divs in Tumblr?

Tags: php, javascript, tags, tumblr, posts

I've thought long and hard about this and I'm really not sure if it's actually possible. It would be really useful if it was though so I'm throwing it out there.

So I need Tumblr posts tagged with XYZ to show up in <*div id="123">, primarily so I can use jquery to make just the XYZ posts popup on their own.

The things I have tried so far:

-Looking through Tumblr documentation for something that specifies posts with specific tags. (No joy.)

-Putting <*iframe src="{name}.tumblr.com/tagged/xyz"> inside <*div id="123">. This does not work because tagged pages show the entire html document of the default tumblr page. So basically it displays the page you're looking at within itself.

-Looking for similar questions brought me to: [Filtering posts by tag on Tumblr page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321548/filtering-posts-by-tag-on-tumblr-page) This looks like it *could* be the right thing, but I really don't understand how to implement it properly. What is the "rest of the code" that the answerer mentions?

Many thanks in advance for all responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, I found the solution here - http://www.godlikemouse.com/code/jquery-ui-tumblr-rss/