# Specify posts to appear on Tumblr custom page

Tags: javascript, api, tumblr

I want to create a custom page and I want posts with a couple of tags (e.g. Photoset and Gifset) to appear on it. I just learned that one way to do this is by using the Tumblr API. I'm not very knowledgeable in javascipt, can someone guide me through this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can filter post by tags.

```
$.getJSON("http://{Name}.tumblr.com/api/read/json?tagged='[WHATEVER TAG YOU SPECIFY]'&callback=?", function(data) {     
    // Rest of code here...         
});
```

I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7324990/2190252).

Comment: So all I need to do is just put this between the <head> tags? Will try this one, thank you.